# Can't redirect from subdomain to main domain

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have 2 projects. First project is in the main domain and the second project is in a subdomain. When I click on a menu item to redirect from subdomain to main domain, it redirects me to: https://subdomain.maindomain.com/https://maindomain.com/

Code:

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Menu 1', 'url' => ['https://maindomain.com/']],
        ['label' => 'Menu 2', 'url' => ['https://maindomain.com/1']],
    ],
]);
```

So I need just redirect to https://maindomain.com/ when click to menu in subdomain project.

Comment: how are you generating the URL?

Comment: @lagbox sorry what is mean? I don't understand

Comment: how are you making the link that they click with the href?

Comment: echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Menu 1', 'url' => ['https://maindomain.com/']],
        ['label' => 'Menu 2', 'url' => ['https://maindomain.com/1']],

        

                ],
            ]);

Comment: `Nav` isn't something that comes with Laravel ... how did you write this to generate the HTML links?  are we supposed to guess at what your code does?

Comment: @lagbox The question has nothing to do with Laravel. It's about Bootstrap and Yii framework.

Comment: @MLFR2kx cool ... this was tagged as laravel originally not yii, check the edits ... glad their issue was resolved

Comment: @lagbox Yes you are right. I noticed the mistake in tagging laravel and changed it to Yii because `Nav::widget` is part of Yii framework which is internally integrated with bootstrap.

Comment: @MLFR2kx very cool, good to know they do some type of integration like that, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting URL outside of brackets. e.g.:

```
['label' => 'Menu 1', 'url' => 'https://maindomain.com/'],
```

Comment: mistake solution, have error)

Comment: Can you tell me the error message?

Comment: thanks! Your answer is correct